# var myFunction = function functionName()

Tags: javascript, function

I always used to write functions like this:

```
var myFunction = function(param) {
    console.log(param);
};
myFunction('myFunction');
```

Now I've seen this:

```
var otherFunction = function whyNameHere(param) {
    console.log(param);
};
otherFunction('otherFunction');
```

and I'm wondering what is `whyNameHere`? When and why should functions be written like this? Also I can call it exactly the same as the `myFunction` function above.. why should someone write `whyNameHere`? Also is there a naming for this kind of function?

If anyone wants to play with it, [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dj045s71/)

Comment: Why do either? You can use ```function otherFunction(param){console.log(param)};```

Comment: It's for call stacks and setting `.name` property, but the question is a dupe.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, your variant not same as ask OP, i sure was a more relevant

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz remove the duplicate because it's not the same question. See what OP ask

Comment: It's not the same question but it's the same answer.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude It's not the same question, but the same answer applies, really.

Comment: I don't see anything related with `var myfunc = function anotherName()` in the answer of the duplicate you've post

Comment: @JasTonAChair it's just a simple example. But most of the times I need a function to return something so I don't know. just how I'm used to do it and to assign a function as a variable

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude If you can add 2 to 2, you can figure out what's going on and how this affects the value created.

Comment: OK, I didn't know they were different. Thanks for raising that @caramba

Comment: @caramba, in nutshell, when in second case you can do: `var otherFunction = function whyNameHere(param) {
    if(condition) whyNameHere(newparam);
};` in first: not

Comment: The second causes an infinite loop

Comment: @Grundy how is that different to `var otherFunction = function whyNameHere(param) { if(condition) otherFunction(newparam); };`?

Comment: @Archer, you can assign another value to `otherFunction` before call it

Comment: In my opinion, it's not a duplicate and the syntax has no sense. This: `var otherFunction = function whyNameHere(param) { whyNameHere("Oh");};` causes an infinite loop, and call `whyNameHere` outside doesn't works, so there is no sense for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using that allows you to set the `.name` property on the created function object.

```
> var f = function g() { }
< undefined
> f.name
< "g"
```

It's impossible to change it later:

```
> f.name = "f"
< "f"
> f.name
< "g"
```

And it's useful for... things.

---

Example:

```
setImmediate(function unicorns() {
    console.log("rainbow");
    throw "glitter";
});
```

Will present itself on the stack trace as:

```
Uncaught glitter
    unicorns @ VM691:4
```

Instead of

```
Uncaught glitter
    (anonymous function) @ VM693:4
```

Comment: [Function.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) This is a new technology, part of the ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) standard. So available not in all browser

Comment: @Grundy maybe it's just me, but for me ES7 is new technology. ES6 has been here for a while, really. Sure, not fully locked and standarized, but you get the point.

Comment: seems to full support ES6 a lot of time

Comment: hmm, well now from what I understood the answers (which my question should be the duplicate of) I could/can use g() only inside f !? so if that is true that would of actually have been the answer on my question (as part one) the seccond part was if that has a name ...

Comment: @caramba The `g` name doesn't leak outside the assignment, if that's what you're asking about.

Comment: well yes thats kind of what I was asking. I didn't see any reason of how and where to use it..

Comment: If you can explain `And it's useful for... things.` with a working example of sense I'll like your answer. I like the joke a lot but it really doesn't helps..

Comment: @caramba sure. There you go.